# Successfully set up Samba share with Ubuntu 19.10 but cannot access with some old devices

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing, cifs

I have created a Samba share with Ubuntu 19.10 the most easy way: In the files browser, right-click on the folder I want to share, select "Local network share", then at first time a prompt will ask to install the Samba (v4.10.7) packages. Similar to the command line:

```
sudo apt install samba samba-common
```

Afterwards, I set up a Samba password for my main user account with this command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a {myusername}
```

Now I can successfully access the shared folder from another Ubuntu or Windows device with my user name and the given Samba password.

However I fail to access using a few years old network media player. It does show the shared network folder and prompt for username and password when trying to connect, but then fails with a simple "cannot access network folder" error.

If I can access the Samba share with a modern computer but not with an older device, what might be the problem?

I had set up Samba shares with older Ubuntu version 16.04 (Samba v3.x) the same way and that still works with my network player.
Maybe an old authentication mode, which I would have to enable with Samba v4?

Comment: Wannacry happened in 2017, which didn't impact Linux/Ubuntu, but did badly impact Microsoft, so they made changes that Linux followed. Ubuntu 16.04 was before the wannacry issues, which is why it worked there, later releases (post-WannaCry) need to be told specifically to work at the lower security level now to be msft compatible, ie. you likely need to specify a `,vers=1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Maybe an old authentication mode, which I would have to enable with Samba v4?
```

That may very well be the issue. You can try editing /etc/samba/smb.conf and adding the following in the [global] section - like right under workgroup = WORKGROUP:

```
lanman auth = yes
ntlm auth = yes
```

THen restarting smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: Great! This almost did it. I also had to add the line `server min protocol = NT1`, now it is working again. :)

Comment: Also, for the other way round I needed `client min protocol = NT1` to be able to access the shares of the network media player with my Ubuntu notebook.